# Logger won't start with an empty file when created for a second time

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a logger for a clean file always that I call the following function:

```
import logging
def create_logger(file_name, level=logging.INFO):
    logger = logging.getLogger(file_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    ch = logging.FileHandler(file_name, mode='w')
    ch.setLevel(level)

    # create formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    # add formatter to ch
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add ch to logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    return logger
```

Yet, when I execute the following twice on a Jupyter notebook:

```
logger = create_logger('test.log')
logger.info('test 0')
```

I get

```
2022-04-28 16:23:56,976 - INFO - test 0
2022-04-28 16:23:56,976 - INFO - test 0
```

How can I make sure that the file is cleared whenever I call the function? (without using os)

Comment: The milliseconds indicate that the two lines are from the same run. And if you have run `create_logger()` twice you will have two handlers attached.

Comment: @KlausD Thanks. I would like to have the file clear and only one logger.

Comment: Then you run the whole logging setup code **once** as early as possible, and get the logger by `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. If you add the same file handler twice the file will become a mess.